# How to add c++ poco library using conan and cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, poco-libraries, conan

I'm a newbie with conan and i want to add poco library to my project using cmake.
I installed poco 1.13.0 using:

`$ conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing`.

Then i used new toolchain with:

`$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

Finally, i tried to add poco headers to my code but got build error: *no such file or directory*. I use CLion, CMake 3.28.1 and Conan 2.0.17. What did i do wrong?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(poco_test)

include_directories(build)

find_package(Poco REQUIRED)

add_executable(poco_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Poco::Poco)
```

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
poco/1.13.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Exception.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @CleanCoder265, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and g++ 11.4.0

Comment: Please paste the log where the entire error that you're experiencing can be seen and on which command it is happening (i.e. cmake --build .)

Comment: @behemoth while the solution by @CleanCoder265 makes it work, I am concerned that this is necessary, in theory ``target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS})`` shouldn't be necessary. This might mean some gap or bug in the ``Poco`` recipe in ConanCenter . If you could file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your setup on my Ubuntu 22.04 with g++13.1.0 and CMake 3.28.3 and it works without any modifications. I'm able to build and run the compiled target.

Based on your description ("no such file or directory"), it seems that you're referring to the error that the compiler doesn't have the include path to Poco's headers.

In your CMakeLists.txt after specifying the executable, you can add:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

---

Q: How did I find Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS?

A: Take a look into the poco's CMake files created during the conan installation, namely: `PocoConfig.cmake` and after it, `Poco-release-x86_64-data.cmake`

Comment: I am a bit surprised by this. In theory this change shouldn't be necessary and ``target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Poco::Poco)`` should contain also the headers information to be found. I am adding a comment in the OP to maybe report an issue, this might be a gap in the ``Poco`` recipe or something to be fixed in ConanCenter maybe?